# how to update a table with specific value from other table with condition from third table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to update my company data 
I have a three tables with large data

Table Name: Accounts

```
id    |    balance    |    currency_id
1          7000            7
2          100             7
3          6000            6
```

Table Name: Members

```
id    |    email
1          ted@gmail.com
2          tom@gmail.com
```

Table Name: Fund

```
email          |    balance
ted@gmail.com       7000
tom@gmail.com       8000
```

how to update Accounts.balance with values from Fund.balance  where the currency_id =7 and  Members.email =  Fund.email

as explained above

how to update accounts.balance from 100 to balance  new value 8000 from Fund table for this email "tom@gmail.com"  as an example ?.

the issue I have is that there is no ID  in Fund table only email which is same as in members tables, so we have to check using the emails instead of id.

Comment: Cannot be done - there is no relationship between accounts and members or accounts and fund - or is there something you aren't tellng us?

Comment: @P.Salmon the relationship between accounts and members is  "id" and members and fund is "email" .

Comment: OK so what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use INNER JOIN to update value in Accounts table from Fund. Make sure related data is available in table Member and Fund.

Note: Try script with test data first.

```
UPDATE Accounts AS A
INNER JOIN Members AS M ON A.ID = M.ID
INNER JOIN Fund AS F ON M.email = F.email
SET A.balance = F.balance
WHERE  A.currency_id =7
```

If there are possibilities of having no data in Fund table for Currency_id = 7 and if you want to keep the old value that case, you can use case as below-

```
SET A.balance = CASE WHEN F.balance IS NULL THEN A.balance ELSE F.balance END
```